# I have a HP Probook 4510s and everytime I plug it in, the monitor dims

Tags: 10.10, laptop, monitor, power-management

anyone else notice this on their laptops, or is it just mine? Ubuntu 10.10 by the way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch Gconf with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in `gconf-editor`
From there you'll search for apps > gnome-power-management > backlight and you'll be able to edit the working/idle dim time. Check the value set when your computer is plugged to AC.

Comment: brightness ac = 100 brightness dim battery = 50, this just does not make sense...

Comment: actually I just tested it, it worked, must have been a bug that they fixed?